# Fancybox works on local computer but not on live website

Tags: jquery, fancybox

On my computer Fancybox works perfectly but when uploaded onto the webserver the live version just opens the images on another page. JQuery and the Fancybox .js files are showing as loaded in firebug although for some reason the css file isn't loading so I just added it to the main css file and as that loads fine.
Firebug shows the following error: $("a.single_image").fancybox is not a function
But that error doesn't occur on the local version. I have tried everything I know of to get it to work but I haven't been able to work out the issue. Could it be something to do with how the web server is configured?
The website page is: http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/early_work.html

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 2):

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js:161

It looks like your jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js is incomplete. Just replace it on your server.

#### Edit

Mind you jquery conflicts with prototype. This may break js all togather in IE for example. So read this:
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Amar is correct; the Javascript file cuts off at line 161. Just look at your web browser's console and you will see this.

Comment: Thanks for the help – I will check out why the server version isn't a full upload and retry. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

You're not pointing to the right place when getting your files:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/builder.js" builder.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/slider.js" slider.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/sound.js" sound.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/controls.js" controls.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/dragdrop.js" dragdrop.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/dragdrop.js" dragdrop.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/controls.js" controls.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/slider.js" slider.js
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.megancampbell.co.nz/scripts/sound.js" sound.js
```

Answer (score 1):

Scriptaculous (1.9.0) requires builder.js, slider.js, sound.js, control.js, dragdrop.js etc. otherwise you get a 404 Not Found error. To remove the 404 Not Found error place all the other .js file in the same directory where scriptaculous.js resides.